# Get info from Array then Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I'm trying to display data after a Fetch. I grouped this data by date so I grouped my objects into an array which have the date as main key.

But now, I'm kind of lost and don't know how to display get the date as Header section then the objects.

This is my data:

```
"31 janvier 2015": Array [
    Object {
      "image": "image",
      "name": "name",
    },
    Object {
      "image": "image",
      "name": "name",
    },
],
"02 février 2016": Array [
    Object {
      "image": "image",
      "name": "name",
    },
    Object {
      "image": "image",
      "name": "name",
    },
]
```

What I would like to do is to display it like a section list :

```
31 janvier 2015
> object
> object
02 février 2016
> object
> object
```

I think I can map the objects but first I have to get the date and go inside that array.

Comment: That data doesn't even look valid to me. I mean are you getting the Array and Object data types in the data or is it you added them?

Comment: It's an example from a console.log()

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an associative array, that is an array that instead of numeric indexes has strings. It works just like an object would if you were for example to do `person['age']` on a person object.

You can loop through the "indexes" with the below code, checking  `hasOwnProperty` to avoid any inherited properties. You can then access your dates by key

```
for (var key in MainArray) {
  if (MainArray.hasOwnProperty(key))
    console.log(MainArray[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the map keys, displaying the date and listing the items.

```
for(let date in list){
  // Date as SECTION HEADING
  console.log(date);
  // access items...
  const items = list[date];
  // Display item
  items.forEach(console.log);
}
```